# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'genpy.rostime'. Trying to load a pickle file

Tags: python-3.x, pickle, ros

I am trying to load a file which is a pickle compatible lists of dictionaries. My code is below:

```
with open('data/task_2/b.obj', 'rb') as file:
   f = pickle.load(file)
```

The error I am getting is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-133-5fce33f1537b> in <module>
      1 with open('data/task_2/b.obj', 'rb') as file:
----> 2     f = pickle.load(file)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'genpy.rostime'
```

I am using windows 10. Python 3.8 and anaconda. First time I tried this piece of code only `genpy` was missing and installed that using `pip`. Now I am stuck with this.

Any hints, suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

solution_1:
install genpy

solution_2:
You should find that where is 'genpy.rostime'.
Then add its root path to your python script.
If the "genpy" is in your current script directory, then the following will solve this problem.

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "."))
```